# Windows equivalents of ns-read-file-name; ns-open-file-using-panel; and, ns-write-file-using-panel

Tags: emacs

In a Windows 32-bit (XP) environment, the directory tree panel only opens when using the mouse on the menu-bar.  When not using a mouse, however, the panel does not open.  `M-x write-file`, for example, does not open the panel when using only the keyboard.  The goal, please, is to create a couple of simple functions that open the directory panel without using the mouse to read / open / save files on Windows XP.  I'm looking for the Windows equivalents for a few basic Emacs OSX functions I've come to enjoy:  `ns-read-file-name`; `ns-open-file-using-panel`; and, `ns-write-file-using-panel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See these variables (which you can bind in your commands): `use-dialog-box`, `use-file-dialog`, and
`w32-use-w32-font-dialog`.

Comment: I didn't find anything directly on-point by Googling using those variables, but I did find a thread describing how to trick Emacs into thinking that the mouse has been used:  `(defadvice find-file-read-args (around find-file-read-args-always-use-dialog-box act) (let ((last-nonmenu-event nil)) ad-do-it))`; and, `(defadvice read-file-name (around read-file-name-always-use-dialog-box act) (let ((last-nonmenu-event nil)) ad-do-it))`.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390602/emacs-m-x-commands-for-invoking-gui-style-menus  Is that the best way?

Comment: Looks reasonable to me.