# Bind File -> Open File with GUI dialog to C-o as global-set-key

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

I want to bind GUI dialog `File -> Open File` to `Ctrl` + `o`

I can `(global-set-key (kbd "C-o") 'find-file)` but I want it exactly with gui.

How can I do it?

Comment: After a bit of looking around, this seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390602/emacs-m-x-commands-for-invoking-gui-style-menus [-]

Comment: @MrBones it's still being not clear how to invoke it there...

Comment: See the answer - I've put the two things together for you.

Comment: @MrBones so far I'm still on command line :(

Comment: I would strongly suggest using GUI emacs instead of running it in a console. Also, I doubt console emacs will open dialogues in X (or whatever) for you. Otherwise, learn `dired-mode` - `C-x d`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`File -> Open File` is just a GUI binding to `find-file`.

By binding it to "C-o", you can then open a file using "C-o". However, this will only bring up the standard `find-file` interface, which uses the echo area.

In order to also get a GUI dialogue box, you need to get emacs to think that `find-file` has been clicked, rather than invoked by keyboard. The solution to that can be found in 
[Emacs M-x commands for invoking "GUI-style" menus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390602/emacs-m-x-commands-for-invoking-gui-style-menus).

Putting the two together (i.e. put them in your .emacs file and evaluate them):

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-o") 'find-file)

(defadvice find-file-read-args (around find-file-read-args-always-use-dialog-box act)
  "Simulate invoking menu item as if by the mouse; see `use-dialog-box'."
  (let ((last-nonmenu-event nil))
     ad-do-it))
```

Note, `C-o` is already bound to `open-line` - which will 'insert a newline and leave point before it`.

Comment: They're not used in emacs. Not by default anyway - modal dialogues are not how emacs does things. You may want to take a look at `dired` (`C-x d`) which may get you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Following the comment by @squidy, here is the complete answer to what the OP asks (tested on emacs 24.3.1):

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-o") 'menu-find-file-existing)
(defadvice find-file-read-args (around find-file-read-args-always-use-dialog-box act)
  "Simulate invoking menu item as if by the mouse; see `use-dialog-box'."
 (let ((last-nonmenu-event nil))
       ad-do-it))
```